# How to run python project on Windows

Tags: python

I'm a mobile dev, no experience with backend environment. I'd appreciate some steps to config my Windows to run python projects, like this one: https://github.com/avilash/TikTokAPI-Python
I can't figure out how to config, run, and test those methods that are described. I assume it should be an IDE for python, but not sure which one is good for Windows, and how ton config it to run a project like this.
On mobile it's a lot easier, just download project, import in the IDE and run it. Any best practices for experienced devs are appreciated!

Comment: Android Studio (Intellij) can run python code just fine

Comment: do you want to create an app from python and that tiktok api

Answer (score 0):

install python on your pc, then do pip3 install -r requirement.txt . I personally prefer vscode. Its the best with required extension installed, or if you are the newbie and you want to learn python, then don't install extension.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the standard Python distro from here https://www.python.org/downloads/. I would stick with versions 3.6 or 3.7 for now for stability and compatibility reasons.
2. Run the installer, the default installation path will be something like `C:\Program Files\Python3X\`. Since you're installing it for the first time, it will be your only installation, so you can choose during the install to set your environment variables (typically including PATH and PYTHONPATH) to point to this installation as the default one.
3. Create your project folder anywhere you like, where you can put your .py scripts. You can then `cd` into the folder in the command line and run any scipt like this `python myscript.py` (or if you haven't set the default env vars `C:\Program Files\Python3X\python.exe myscript.py`).

This is the bare minimum you need to be able to run Python projects.

4. To install the package you mentioned, in the command line type `pip install git+https://github.com/avilash/TikTokAPI-Python` (or `C:\Program Files\Python3X\Scripts\pip.exe install git+https://github.com/avilash/TikTokAPI-Python`). This will work because the project has a setup script (`setup.py`). Note that this will install it into the Python installation folder and you will NOT be able to modify it. If you want to be able to do development on it, clone it into a separate folder, navigate into it and install in 'dev' mode from the current folder using `pip install -e .` (note the dot!)
5. For the IDE, you can use VS Code if you're already using it, just install the Python extension. If you're more into IntelliJ, you can then use PyCharm which will have the familiar interface but it's a separate IDE. Both are similarly good in terms of features and maturity.

Other notes you can find useful at the beginning:

- If you install multiple Python installation in different places, they are pretty much self-contained and defined by their installation path, but of course the one for which you will select to set the environment vars during installation will be the default one. If you want to run the `pip` command for a specific installation, then you will have to use `C:\Program Files\Python3X\python.exe -m pip install ...`.
- `pip` is Python package manager, typically you can install anything available on `https://pypi.org/` with just `pip install pandas` for example.
- You can check all packages installed using `pip list`. Since `pip` itself is also just a Python package, it will always be in the list as it's installed by default when you install Python.